# Build docker com node angular

Tags: angular, angularjs-directives, docker

estou precisando de uma ajudinha com relação ao Docker, preciso buildar para gerar uma imagem, mas estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> Step 9/10 : COPY --from=angular /app/dist/docker-softplayer
> /usr/share/nginx/html ERROR: Service 'softplayer-angular' failed to
> build : COPY failed: stat
> /var/lib/docker/overlay2/487f7260d0a1b1134efd0cf9c5c2da21697ccaf2354f64ee971dc3c1c78e5d2e/merged/app/dist/docker-softplayer:
> no such file or directory The terminal process
> "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /d /c docker-compose  up -d --build"
> terminated with exit code: 1.

O erro até que é bem claro, ele diz que não encontrou nenhum arquivo ou diretório com esse nome no nginx, o problema é que se eu retirar o COPY que gera esse erro ele até builda, mas ele aparece apenas a tela de Welcome do nginx, então vi um tutorial da Loyane onde ela diz para usar esse COPY e por isso uso ele, é a primeira vez que gero uma imagem docker então não entendo muito das partes técnicas, mas já vi que existe o docker-ignore que poderia esta causando esse erro, mas já adianto que não uso esse docker-ignore, o nome do meu aplicativo no package.json é docker-softplayer.

Meu Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10 as angular
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
VOLUME /var/cache/nginx
COPY --from=angular /app/dist/docker-softplayer /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar nisso por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Ajustei meu Dockerfile da seguinte forma e resolveu meu problema:

```
FROM node:10 as angular
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
VOLUME /var/cache/nginx
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=angular /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```